# working with log4net package

Tags: c#, log4net

I recently added the log4net package in to my WCF web application. now I have few questions I:

1. I added the log4net package through the VS 2013 package install and
   it added whole package. My guess is that log4net is just the dll and I can add it to my project just by adding the dll?
2. when I added log4net package a packages.config file has been added to my project with this content:

   ```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
   <packages>
     <package id="log4net" version="2.0.3" targetFramework="net45" />
   </packages>
   ```

what is it? can I remove it?

3. Can I use the log4net all over my project without defining it in top of each class?
4. I want to add a extra field to message part. for example I want to log the events like this:

   Log.Debug(IP,"This is a DEBUG level message.  Typically your most VERBOSE level.");

and the log file show it like this:

```
72 DEBUG 2015-06-16 08:17:41,713 [10] [(null)] [InsertDate] - from source IP(192.168.1.1) This is a DEBUG level message.  Typically your most VERBOSE level.
```

5. I also added `%line` in to conversionPattern but it doesn't work. every time it start from 72. How can this be fixed?
6. How can log the application stop and start in the wcf application?

Comment: If you are using it throughout your app, you will need to reference the assembly in each class that is going to use it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You actually asked 4 questions in 1.
First, you need to understand that you have used a NuGet package manager and it is a good practice to include available packages using NuGet but not manually as it automatically places package in a proper place, lets you add this package easily to other projects of solution, provides versioning etc.
Read more about NuGet. For example, [here](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/IntroducingNuGetPackageManagementForNETAnotherPieceOfTheWebStack.aspx).

Now about your questions:

**First**: No, `log4net` package contains not only a `log4net.dll` file. It also has `log4net.xml` file. Yes, you can add these two files manually without using NuGet package manager.

**Second**: It is a list of NuGet packages in your project. You can only remove it if you are not going to use NuGet. However, it is not a good idea - let it be there, it is a single light-weight XML-file.

**Third**: It's a question of OOP. Create a singleton global logger, for example:

```
public static class LoggingFactory
{
    private static ILog _logger;

    private static ILog CreateLogger()
    {
        // Some log4net initialization
        return LogManager.GetLogger("Logger");
    }

    public static ILog GetLogger()
    {
        return _logger ?? (_logger = CreateLogger());
    }
}

public class AnyClassOfYourWholeSolution
{
    LoggingFactory.GetLogger().DebugFormat("{0} {1}", a, b);
}
```

**Fourth:** It is a question of OOP again. Create an adapter and use it:

```
public interface ILogger
{
    void Debug(string ip, string message);
    void Info(string ip, string message);
    void Error(string ip, string message);
}

public class Log4NetLogger : ILogger
{
    private ILog  _logger;

    public Log4NetLogger() 
    {
        // Some log4net initialization
        _logger = LogManager.GetLogger("Logger");
    }

    public void Debug(string ip, string message)
    {
        // ...
    }

    public void Info(string ip, string message)
    {
        // ...
    }

    public void Error(string ip, string message)
    {
        // ...
    }
}

public static class LoggingFactory
{
    private static ILogger _loggerAdapter;

    private static Initialize(ILogger adapter)
    {
        _loggerAdapter = adapter;
    }

    public static GetLogger()
    {
        return _logger;
    }
}

public class BeginningOfYourProject 
{
    // Main() or Global.asax or Program.cs etc.
    LoggingFactory.Initialize(new Log4NetLogger());
}

public class AnyClassOfYourWholeProject
{
    LoggingFactory.GetLogger().Debug(ip, message);
}
```

Or you can extract ip to the properties of log4net:

```
// During initialization
log4net.ThreadContext.Properties["ip"] = ip;

// log4net Config
<layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout">
    <conversionPattern value="%n%-5p %d %t IP: %property{ip} %m" />
</layout>
```

It is all up to your fantasy.

Comment: Awesome answer, from a person whose never used Log4Net.  Very verbose and to the point.